# Running an exe file from VBA access

Tags: python, ms-access

I'm trying to run an exe file created from a Python script. This little program (`PostLif.exe`) posts XML files to pension funds and reads answers back.

The program works when executed independently, but when I try to run it from Access using:

```
Call Shell(strfolder & "\PostLif", vbNormalFocus)
```

The terminal window opens briefly, but the program does not execute. The same command runs a simple "hello world" program created from a Python script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest debugging this by creating a batch file that runs your executable and has a `pause` command so you can see what happens before the window closes

Comment: Hi Martin,
Yes, I was thinking to do that. The executable file is accessing the internet, and I was wondering if there was some permission issue, or some special parameter that was needed in the Shell command. But I will try to locate exactly where it stops and hopefully that will bring me closer. 
Thanks - Tolli

Comment: Try to add `.exe` after file name part

Comment: If blanks in path, command needs to be surrounded by doublq-qutoes as blanks seperate arguments in command-line.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What about using **[Application.FollowHyperlink method (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.application.followhyperlink)**?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. My error was a beginners one. Clicking on the program in its folder is not the same as running it from a VBA script. In this case anyway, when running from the Access VBA script, the program does not know what the working directory is. Once I changed the command to include the working directory as a parameter when calling the program it worked fine. My command was like this:

Call Shell("""" & postbreyta & """ """ & strfolder & """", vbNormalFocus)

Where 'postbreyta' is the full path and program name of the program (C:\salaries\pension\postpension.exe) and 'strfolder' is the working directory (passed as a parameter), in my case the same (C:\salaries\pension)

Tolli